# Whomever from the show "The Office"

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses, whoever-vs-whomever

So there is an infamous comedy sketch with "whomever" vs "whoever" in the show "the Office". The correct answer there is that you cannot tell which is the correct answer because the sentence was unfinished. The problem with this answer is that it requires university level knowledge in linguistics (it needs cites like Groos, Anneke, and Henk van Riemsdijk. 1981. Matching effects in free relatives: A parameter of core grammar. Theory of markedness in generative grammar, ed. by A. Belleti, L. Brandi, and L. Rizzi, 177-216. Pisa: Scuola Normale Superiore).

See "It could depend on how Ryan would have completed the sentence if he hadn’t stopped at whomever" in this https://literalminded.wordpress.com/2007/10/21/whomever-is-never-actually-right/

Can you tell me whether this analysis is correct?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143067/discussion-on-question-by---whomever-from-the-show-the-offic); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This whole discussion is premised on the idea that "whoever" (or "whomever") must always introduce a subordinate clause. On this basis, it is assumed that there must be an implicit subordinate clause after "whomever," and that the choice between "whoever" and "whomever" must be determined by the use of that pronoun within the (omitted) subordinate clause. So one might conclude that, with the subordinate clause incomplete, we have no basis for deciding which form to use, at least in formal English that makes the who/whom distinction.

But it seems much simpler to posit that this is just a *separate meaning* of "whoever," one ultimately separate from its use as a relative pronoun.  That is [how TfD lists it:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whoever)

> *informal* an unknown or unspecified person: *give those to John, or Cathy, or whoever.*

So, should "whoever" be used (as in the above example), or is it "whomever"? The answer is that the whoever/whomever distinction only exists in formal English. But this sense of "whoever" only exists in informal English. So **this problem simply never arises:** in formal contexts you would only use "who(m)ever" with a true subordinate clause (or in interrogatives), whereas in informal contexts the form "whomever" would never be used.

This is the problem with Ryan's reasoning. He is trying to apply a rule only used in formal English to a sense of a word only used in informal English. The only sensible answer, if this sense of "whoever" is being used, is to always choose the form **whoever.**

This is, of course, exactly the point that the OP makes:

> On the other hand, maybe it’s ridiculous to imagine how Ryan would have completed the sentence. Though I may be succumbing to the Recency Illusion, it’s my impression that standalone *whoever* (and whatever, wherever, whenever) developed years after the purely syntactic rule for who(m)ever had faded from common knowledge, so why would I expect it to have arisen with any allegiance to this rule? Given that it emerged among a generation of speakers who mostly forgot, remembered imperfectly, or never knew the syntactic rule regarding whomever, I’d expect standalone who(m)ever to follow the more prominent, emerging sociolinguistic rule — use whomever in formal settings. This seems to be how Ryan is using it, as a boss addressing a subordinate and wanting to project as much authority as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant sentence is:

> Ryan: What I really want, honestly Michael, is for you to know it, so that you can communicate it to the people here, to your clients, to whomever.

You say:

> The correct answer there is that you cannot tell which is the correct answer because the sentence was unfinished.

This is not so: It isn't unfinished. You can see that there is a full stop/period at the end.

Simplified, it is

Ryan: What I really want is for you to know it, so that you can communicate it to whomever.

**whomever** is in the object case as it is the object of the preposition "to".

whomever is marked, as you will see, as "literary": nevertheless, is a word:

OED

> **whomever**, pron. *literary*.
>
> **The objective case of whoever pron.; as direct object, or object of prep.** (Less frequent than whomsoever pron.)
>
> **a. As nominal relative, or with correlative in principal clause (with constructions as in whoever pron. 1): Any (one) whom.**
>
> 1920   M. Beerbohm And Even Now 189   *To impose his will on whomever
> he sees comfortably settled.*

Comment: The case of a relative pronoun (in formal English) is determined by its use in the relative clause itself, not by its use in the matrix clause. For the example: "The man, whom I had seen before, looked very tired." Here the "to" is in the matrix clause.

Comment: It was unfinished in a sense you can continue it in two ways and it can be whomever or whoever.

Comment: @alphabet That is wrong and misleading. The completely simplified clause is *so that you can communicate it to whomever*. The case of whomever is governed by to. Compare *You can communicate it **to him.***

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников *It was unfinished in a sense...* It is either unfinished or finished. The man had stopped speaking. There is a full stop/period. It has ended. You can **always** add something to a sentence but that is not the point.

Comment: @Greybeard See my answer below. If it's a relative pronoun it's ambiguous since the "to" is in the matrix clause; compare "to the man who I met" vs "to the man whom he met." Fortunately it isn't a relative pronoun, though, so this is all irrelevant.

Comment: @alphabet - it doesn't matter where it is - it is the object of a preposition.